# Aerospike client AddAndGet documentation method

Tags: documentation, aerospike

newbies question

I'm new with aerospike client and i'm searching for a method documantion ..
I've only found [this link](http://www.aerospike.com/java_api/index.html)  and [that one](https://docs.aerospike.com/display/AS2/Overview+of+API+Functions) .. but it's not enough..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `operate` function in the AerospikeClient class. Here is the [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/java_api/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html) for it. `operate` function lets you perform multiple [operations](http://www.aerospike.com/java_api/com/aerospike/client/Operation.html) in a single call to the server. You have to specify `add` and `get` operations for your need.

There is a nice example demonstrating your use-case. When you download the java client, look at the file examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/Add.java.